# How to swap the numbers row on azerty keyboards in vim only while being in normal mode?

Tags: vim

Hi I'm learning Vim and it looks like the shortcuts have been designed for qwerty keyboards. In normal mode you often need to type `number motion` to get around. How would one do to configure vim so it interprets `&é"'(-è_çà` as `1234567890` only while being in normal mode ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you want to accomplish, but I strongly advise you not to try to change the default mappings as a beginner too early.

For example you want to remap `"` to a number. That is a bad idea, because you can no longer use really important things like `ci"` (changes text inside double quotes), `dt"` (deletes everything from the cursor to the first `"` in a line) and so on. You will lose a lot of functionality if you remap those keys, and I don't see any positive things you achieve with it.

Of course there is a way to remap keys if you really want to, put the following into your `.vimrc` and source it (e.g. by entering `:so %` when your `.vimrc` is open):

```
" map & to 1 in normal mode
nnoremap & 1
```

**edit**:

Okay, I think I understand your problem now, after having a look at the [AZERTY-keyboards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AZERTY).

Just change the mapping for each key like this:

```
" map & to 1 in normal mode
nnoremap & 1
" map 1 to & in normal mode
nnoremap 1 &
```

Do the same for all the other keys as well.

Comment: i want to swap & with 1 and so on (shift-& to type &) so i'm not removing anything